# Dynamically allocated pointer to a structure not returning from C function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to write a concordance program using a linked list in C.  To do this, I am returning a pointer to a dynamically allocated structure from a function.  However, the address of the pointer in the function doesn't match the address of the returned value.  The relevant code is below.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ...
    struct wordlist *a = NULL;
    ...
    a = firstNode(word);
    printf("%p\n",(void*)&a);
    ...
}

struct wordlist * firstNode(char *fileWord){
    struct wordlist *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    newNode->word = fileWord;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->previous = NULL;
    printf("%s\n",newNode->word);
    printf("%p\n",(void*)&newNode);
    return newNode;
}
```

When I print the address of newNode, it is always different than when I print the value of a in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you printing what you return?

No.

You are printing the wrong thing.

```
 printf("%p\n",newNode);
```

Now you will see the value you return and value you print will match. Previously you were returning on thing and printing another.

#### Explanation

Earlier you were allocating memory dynamically and the returned value of `malloc` is stored in local variable `newNode`. Now you are printing `newNode`'s address. Not what `newNode` contains which is returned from the function.

Also check the return value of `malloc`. De-allocate dynamically allocated memory.